# Comparing 2 Javascript arrays and updating based on if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

Given the below array already sorted by "startDate" I'm trying to compare which objects have "startDate" that occur after the previous object "endDate".

```
 overlapList = [
   {elem: <div id="task7">, startDate: 918, endDate: 1053, order: 1}
   {elem: <div id="task8">, startDate: 973, endDate: 1108, order: 2}
   {elem: <div id="task3">, startDate: 1026, endDate: 1647, order: 3}
   {elem: <div id="task6">, startDate: 1053, endDate: 1188, order: 4}
   {elem: <div id="task5">, startDate: 1107, endDate: 1242, order: 5}
   {elem: <div id="task4">, startDate: 1188, endDate: 1323, order: 6}
 ]
```

If true, the order number of the compared object is updated to match. The desired output would be:

```
 overlapList = [
   {elem: <div id="task7">, startDate: 918, endDate: 1053, order: 1}
   {elem: <div id="task8">, startDate: 973, endDate: 1108, order: 2}
   {elem: <div id="task3">, startDate: 1026, endDate: 1647, order: 3}
   {elem: <div id="task6">, startDate: 1053, endDate: 1188, order: **1**}
   {elem: <div id="task5">, startDate: 1107, endDate: 1242, order: **2**}
   {elem: <div id="task4">, startDate: 1188, endDate: 1323, order: **1**}
 ]
```

As objects are added to the array, the script would look at the max "endDate" number for the give "order".

I thought the best approach would be to dynamically add to a second array (maxOrderEnd) to compare against the first array that would keep track of the max "endDate" and the respective "order".

The "if" statement would always look at the smallest "order" number first to determine if the "startDate" of an object is greater than the "order" "endDate". If false, it would move to the next "order" number and compare. If no existing "order" number matched the criteria is the "maxOrderEnd" array, a new "order" number would be added to "maxOrderEnd" array.

Given the "overlapList" array above, the end result of "maxOrderEnd" array would be:

```
maxOrderEnd = [
  {endDateMax: 0, order: 0}
  {endDateMax: 1323, order: 1}
  {endDateMax: 1242, order: 2}
  {endDateMax: 1647, order: 3}
]
```

I tried writing the following script but keep running into an order loop issue:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < overlapList.length; i++){
     maxOrderEnd = [{endDateMax: 0, order: 0}];
        overlapList.forEach(function(start){
            var addOrder = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < maxOrderEnd.length; i++){

                        var less = maxOrderEnd.filter(function(item){ return start.startDate + 1 > item.endDateMax})[i];
                            if (less){
                                maxOrderEnd.push({endDateMax: start.endDate, order: addOrder}),
                                addOrder = addOrder + 1;
                            }
                            else {start.order = maxOrderEnd.order, maxOrderEnd.endDateMax = start.endDate;
                            }
                            console.log(addOrder);
            }
        });
    }

console.log(overlapList);
console.log(maxOrderEnd);
```

Comment: Not really clear what *"order number of the compared object is updated to match"* means exactly

Comment: Use an object where `order` used as key ... update `endDateMax` in loop as approprate. Then map object to array once you have all the `endMax`

Comment: In "overlapList", "task 6" is compared to all objects in the "maxOrderEnd" array to find where the "overlapList.endDate" of "task 6" is greater than "maxOrderEnd.endDateMax". If true, the "overlapList.order" would update to what the "maxOrderEnd.order" would be ("1" in the "task 6" case) and then update respective "maxOrderEnd.endDateMax" with "overlapList.endDate" (updating from 1053 to 1188).